# Тип данных в результатах выборки

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Это нормально, что `SELECT * FROM table` всегда возвращает массив `string`, независимо от типа данных столбцов? Хотелось бы целые получать как `int` сразу, а не приводить к нужному типу уже в PHP.

Проверил результаты MySQLi, PDO, родной библиотеки CodeIgniter – везде массив строковых значений. Пытался найти в интернете, можно ли явно указывать тип в запросе, но не нашёл.

Comment: Да в общем-то какая разница в `php` между `1` и `"1"`. Оба значения и суммировать можно и конкатенацию делать.

Comment: @Visman я люблю в `php` делать тождественные сравнения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для РНР это в принципе нормально. И особо рассчитывать на строгую типизацию не стоит. К примеру, по НТТР к нам приходят только строки, и ничего кроме строк.

Но получать тип (особенно - NULL) из БД действительно бывает удобно. И новые API для работы с mysql этот функционал поддерживают.

Для этого нужно, чтобы PDO и mysqli были скомпилированы с поддержкой **mysqlnd**, о чем в соответствующих разделах вывода phpinfo() должна быть соответствующая запись.

Плюс, в некоторых случаях, для получения желаемого эффекта надо запрашивать результат с помощью подготовленных выражений.

Comment: Понятно, значит рассчитывать на это не стоит. Даже если у меня будет собрано, у хостера наверняка нет.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, получилось.

Проверил `phpinfo()`, поддержка **mysqlnd** есть. Эксперимента ради залез в CodeIgniter'e в драйвер БД `DB_driver.php` и вставил после подключения к базе данных строчку:

```
$this->connect->options(MYSQLI_OPT_INT_AND_FLOAT_NATIVE, true);
```